# Annihilator of a maximal ideal in a polynomial ring[updated]

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R = k[x, y]$ be the polynomial ring in two variables and $I$ an ideal of $R$ such that $R/I$ is finite dimensional. I wonder if the following statement is correct?

If $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal in $R/I$, then its annihilator in $R/I$ is nonzero.

Here, I assume $k$ is algebraically closed. Thanks!

Comment: Annihilator with respect to which ring? The ring $R$ or the ring $R/I$?

Comment: I referred to the annihilator in $R/I$.

Comment: In an Artinian ring every maximal ideal has a non-zero annihilator, unless it's a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R/I$ is finite-dimensional, the product of all (finitely many) maximal ideals is the nilradical, in particular the annihilator of any maximal ideal is non-zero.

Comment: This is much simpler. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $I=0$ and take $M=(x-a,x-b)$ its annihilator is zero.

Comment: Oops. That's correct. What if I assume $I \neq 0$?

Comment: You can take $I$ to be the ideal which defines an integral curve $C$. In this case $k[x,y]/I$ is integral. If you take the ideal which defines a point of  $C$, its annihilator is zero.

Comment: Thanks, Tsemo. If I further assume $R/I$ is finite dimensional, would my statement be true?

Comment: If $R/I$ is finite dimensional, then it is a product $k^n$ since $I$ defines a variety which is a finite set of points.

Comment: I guess you meant $R/I$ modulo its radical? $R/(x - a, y- b)^2$ is finite dimensional, but it is not isomorphic to $k$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I have assumed that $I$ is a radical ideal.